# Applying physics to hair in Blender 3

Tags: animation, particles, physics, baking, hair

When i apply physics to an object and press space button object is moving but hair is not moving.
I was advised to bake the hair stimulation in the hair particles system cache settings, however, that didn't work for me.

I watched a YouTube video were the user enables the advanced setting and hair dynamics, unfortunately, following the same steps didn't work in my case. Is there something I should do different since I'm using Blender 3.0?

Comment: pls provide your blend file so we can check it out...or watch again the tutorial carefully and follow each step which is taken. But without seeing any settings of your work we cannot say what you did wrong so pls improve your question. Thanks. And a link to the tutorial you watched would help too.

Comment: Is not about blend file i just click shift A and add  uv sphere or cube after that i click on particle properties and add hair   after that i click on physics properties and add rigid body to object  but when i click space button object is moving due to gravity but hair is not moving with object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add UV-Sphere, add rigid body, choose source "base"

[image]

add particle system, hair, check hair dynamics

result:

[image]

Note: if you just "change" your particle system i might be necessary to delete your cache